# The className in react-select doesent apply

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, drop-down-menu, react-select

I just started using react-select and when I try to add my styles using scss they dont apply, I know that there is option for styles where you set option styles as well as control but I want a cleaner way using scss

Here is what I want:

[image]

Here is what I get after applying className:

[image]

Is there a way to disable the preset styles so I can make my own or how can I modify it so it takes my real styles here is my css:

```css
.shippingCountryDropdownElement {
  border: none;
  height: 42px;
  background-color: red;
  color: gray;
  outline: none;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 21px;
  cursor: pointer;
  &:focus {
    box-shadow: none;
  }
}
```

And if not is there a better solution for a dropdown than this library, any help would be great. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: you might want to add `!important` after the css values like `border: none !important;`

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen nop didnt fix it

Answer (score 1):

For the `react-select` component, you will be able to modify it's default style like this:

```css
// To Hide Indicator Line
.shippingCountryDropdownElement .select__indicator-separator {
  display: none;
}

// To Hide Border Around Field
.shippingCountryDropdownElement .select__control {
  border: 0px;
}
```

You can refer [here](https://react-select.com/styles) for more details on this.

Comment: First thing thank you for answering and second the thing is Im using scss.module so when I tried to apply prefix like classNamePrefix={styles.select} it didnt work do you know how can I implement scss into it, thank you in advance

Comment: @Vedo You can pass `className="shippingCountryDropdownElement"` as prop which will add this CSS class to the element and after that you just have to apply above provided CSS.